# Redux and React: How to figure out what triggered a mapStateToPropsCall?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a situation where an http call fails and an error message is rendered, but then additional state changes occur after that and render is called multiple times subsequently. Is there some trick to determine what caused the state change (and hence the mapStateToProps call) or I suppose I could hand roll some code to do an object comparison.

Update: Here's the mapStateToProps() call for the component I'm currently dealing with:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    groups: state.group,
    response: state.response,
    card: state.card,
    rounds: state.round
  };
};
```

Although I suppose it's not just a change to the global store (which in turn could cause the props to change) that will potentially cause render() to get called, but also any setState() calls. Taking a step back, I'm wondering if when folks are troubleshooting react-redux issues, this is something they pay attention to, i.e. what specific state changes caused render() to get called?

Comment: Can you post some example code?

Comment: You could add a middleware logging the action and the payload, but for the rest, there will be some debugging that needs to be done ;) Also render is not so much a problem, it gets called more often and then compared to the virtual DOM. If you have potential performance issues, you could theoretically check to handle changes through `shouldComponentUpdate` but well, for that there is not enough code shown (ie the components that you are rendering, what your provider looks like or what is your state)

Comment: I take it you have Redux Dev Tools Chrome extension: https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools - you can see which actions are being dispatched, also replay actions - it should be fairly simple then to see which dispatch caused state change and subsequent ```mapState..``` calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've since added redux toolkit into the call which includes redux dev tools. Redux dev tools has a chrome plugin with an inspector which will show all of the redux actions that are being issued.